# Magento div position changing

Tags: magento

I need to change the position of div in my magento page

Discount Code should be placed to the left, Middle  Shipping Estimation 
Based on you selection should come at the bottom horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the exact html page what you need to change. But according to the template the file location may change. You can find the location by going to

system ->configuration ->Developer(left bottom)  then select Main Web site from the current configuration(left top)
Then you can select YES for the Template Path Hints in the Debug section. with that you will be able to see the file location in your root.

After that you change the div location as you need :)